# Hide Everything For Cmd+Space Spotlight Search but Applications

Tags: high-sierra, spotlight, search

I am trying to use Spotlight as a way to solely launch my most used applications.

A lot of them have similar names, so for me Spotlight displaying in a linear down list works much better then lets say Launchpad which displays them in something like a column/row combination.

Anyways I am trying to both speed up Spotlight and prevent it from displaying false positives by hiding everything but applications.

I did this by effectively unchecking everything but Applications in System Preferences → Spotlight → Search Results, and then by preventing indexing of my home folder directly.

The problem is now I can't search my Mac for anything. This solved 1 issue while creating another.

Is there a way to feasible make Spotlight search only applications while everything else search globally?

Comment: and  it has to be with Cmd+Space

Comment: @Buscar웃 hmm any keyboard shortcut would work fine.   I mean they can always be reassigned.

Comment: so something that shows you most recently used Apps ? and the Apple Menu is not it

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes.  If I could dream Recently used.  Alphabet list and searchable for Applications. I would like it to work most similar to sigh the windows dock as possible, but right now I have found and I am using alfred.  It works okay but I really dislike the font size and have it display in the center screen instead I don't know in a corner or side of the screen.  Related question I have asked https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52095/alternative-to-launchpad-mac

Comment: and the Apple menu is not it ? it shows recent apps and documents

Comment: @Buscar웃 no I want them all like an Alphabetical list.  Right now I have added the Applications folder to the dock and made it a list.

Comment: How about a Service where you press e.g. `⇧⌘Space` to click the Applications Dock Tile so you can then type one, two or three letters, as necessary together, to highlight the target app and then press Enter to open it? Or a Service that only show the apps you want either in a Dock Tile like the Applications Dock Tile or a Choose from List dialog where you can select, etc.?

Comment: if you type "Application kind:App" in Spotlight it only shows Applications. However not sorted by date/time

Comment: @user3439894 the first sounds great.  The 2nd I'm not exactly sure what you are saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is in response to conversation in comments with the OP.

With the **Applications** folder already added to the **Dock** and **View content as** set to **List**...

The following process will allow the **Applications Dock Tile** to be programmatically clicked with a keyboard shortcut as an **Automator** *service*. It requires an **AppleScript** *application* and the **Automator** *service*. This is done this way so as to avoid having to add every app that has focus when pressing the assigned keyboard shortcut of having to be explicitly granted ***Accessibility Access***. Only the **AppleScript** *application* will need permission.

First create the **AppleScript** *application*...

In **Script Editor** add the following **AppleScript** *code* to a new document and save it as **File Format: Application**, e.g.: **Click Applications Dock Tile**

```
tell application "System Events"
    click UI element "Applications" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
end tell
```

Add the **AppleScript** *application*, e.g. **Click Applications Dock Tile**, to **Accessibility** in...

- **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

Now create the **Automator** *service*...

In **Automator**:

1. **File** > **New**, or press: **⌘N**
2. Select **Service** and click the **Choose** button.
3. Set the settings as shown in the first image below.
4. Add a **Launch Application** *action*.
5. Save as e.g.: **Click Applications Dock Tile**

[image: Click Applications Dock Tile Automator Service]

In **System Preferences**...

- **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** add **⇧⌘Space** (press Shift-Command-Space) to the **Click Applications Dock Tile** *service*, as shown in the image below.

  - Note: A word about the shortcut you assign... **⇧⌘Space** is offered as a suggestion however, you'll need to select one that doesn't conflict with any app that has focus when pressed. This may require a strange combination or a four character combo. YMMV

[image: Services Shortcuts]

---

Now when pressing the set key combo, the **Applications Dock Tile** will be clicked and you can then type one, two or three letters, as necessary together, to highlight the target app and then press **Enter** to open it.

---

Another approach is to setup a folder with *aliases* to just the core group of regularly used apps, adding it to the **Dock** and modifying the steps as appropriate. Or use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to create a *dialog box* that will appear mid-center screen to choose from:

```
set myAppList to {"Calculator", "Calendar", "Contacts", "Dictionary", "DVD Player", "Firefox", "Safari"}
choose from list myAppList
if (count result) > 0 then
    set appToOpen to item 1 of result
    do shell script "open -a " & quoted form of appToOpen
end if
```

Just change the app names in the `myAppList` *list* to the core group of regularly used apps. The apps shown are just to show what it would look like. BTW If you use this as an app, add an `activate` *command* before the `choose from list` *command*.

You can type one, two or three letters, as necessary together, to highlight the target app and then press **Enter** to open it. Or use down or up arrow or click and press Enter or click OK or double click the target. Lots of options.

[image: choose from list dialog box]

---

As a side note, if you use a program like [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), you only need to create the **AppleScript** *code* as a **.scpt** not an **.app** and can assigned the keyboard shortcut in the **Preferences** for **FastScripts**. None of the other instructions apply unless you want to do it all natively without the use of third-party software.

<sub>Note that I am not affiliated with the developer of FastScripts, just a satisfied user.</sub>

Comment: In your first technique it would be nice if the shortcut opened and closed the menu so if you press it once it opens and press it a second time it closes it.

Comment: @William, You can simply press the **Esc** key to dismiss the menu if you choose not to open an app after initially pressing **⇧⌘Space** (or whatever key combo you've assigned). Unfortunately because of the nature of how this has to trigger the service and run a secondary application it's not conducive to trapping the initial key sequence a second time to work in the same manner as Spotlight does. This answer was just to provide some alternative workarounds, it's not perfect but what workarounds are.

Comment: I like this answer the most because it doesn't require a 3rd party application.  I have not had time to mess with it yet but I think it may be possible to detect if the application is currently open to decide if it should run the command again or close the application.

Comment: Before I mark this as an answer, I'm curious if there is any way maybe using Autohotkey to speed up the opening of the list.  Although it certainly works it seems to sometimes have some serious lag in just opening the service application.

Comment: @William It is my understanding, and could be wrong, that AutoHotkey is a Windows app not an macOS app however, as a result of changes made to OS X/macOS in the last 3 or 4 major releases regarding UI Scripting and Security this solution of using Automator to launch another app that the app being launched only having to be added to Security & Privacy ... is the best way to do things globally and natively, and why I switched to using FastScripts for the things I used an Automator service that only relied on AppleScript. It's free for up to 10 keyboard shortcuts and unlimited is IIRC ~$10 USD.

Comment: I meant Karabiner Elements(not autohotkey) sigh I use both and switch back and forth.

Comment: @William, I have not used Karabiner Elements, so I cannot speak to it however, if it's capable of of running a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript then I don't see an issue. I guess I can check out Karabiner Elements and see what it can do.

Comment: @William, Things can be sped up a bit natively by not having the AppleScript app's Dock Tile show on the Dock. However there can be an issue after making the necessary change with the Info.plist of the app and may not reauthorize after the change Then the app has to be recreated with a different spelling, make all the changes to the AppleScript app before its added back to Security & Privacy... I actually did that on mine and it seemed to work a bit faster faster. I actually was going to update the answer with the steps the day after I posted it but haven't found the time to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In direct respond to your Title

> Hide Everything For Cmd+Space Spotlight Search but Applications

This will work if you type it in Spotlight

> Application kind:App

Now it only shows Applications sorted by most recent and frequently used.

[image]

If you then expand it with NOT, you can exclude apps you do not want to see

> Application kind:app NOT Safari NOT Automator

Of course you could Automate this, but that would be another question on how ?

Comment: This is a technically correct answer but in practicality this is surely not what I think anyone would want for frequent opening of certain applications.

Comment: @William you can automate it

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for a second tool to just launch applications. I would check out the free to use Launcher by a long term Apple developer - obdev.at

- https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html

Since spotlight by design is one database only - why not let spotlight index everything and add a second tool that only indexes applications for quick launching. Two of the many benefits of Launchbar are it's way faster than spotlight in my use across dozens of computers and OS versions and that you can define custom shortcuts for specific apps and not have to depend on what spotlight thinks is the correct shortcut.

As a bonus, it also learns as you type to prioritize and learn the short cuts you mean over time. It's uncanny how well it works.